# SharePoint Config database grown up to 2TB

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I recent discovered our SharePoint Config database has grown up to 2TB when I wanted to create a new Web Application and new Search Service. I received error:

> The transactional log database: SharePoint_Config is full due to LOG_BACKUP

I wanted to set the Autogrowth in SQL Management Studio to "Unlimited" but it gave error "Value of '2097216' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'"

Please how do I solve this problem?

Kindly see the attached images
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

I wanted to set the Autogrowth in SQL Management Studio to "Unlimited" but it gave error "Value of '2097216' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'"

Comment: The transaction log, not the database. Which means it hasn't been backed up in a long time. The solution is to take regular backups, not try to increase the maximum file size

Comment: Since you are not taking log backups now - switch the recovery model on the database from full to simple.  Shrink the log file (not the database - just the log file) - repeat the shrink operation until you get it to something less than 2GB (2048MB).  Once that is done - switch the recovery model back to full, backup the database - and create a job to backup the log every 5 minutes.